# Boundaries of integration/change of variables

Tags: probability

We consider a pair of independent random variables $(X,Y)$ with joint probability density $$f(x,y)=\lambda\mu e^{-(\lambda x+\mu y)}\mathbb{1}_{\{(x,y)\in(0,\infty)^2\}}\qquad (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$$

Find the joint distribution of $S:=X+Y$ and $U:=\frac{X}{X+Y}$.

Okay, I did the following:

$\mathbb{E}(g(S,U))=\int_{(0\times\infty)^2} g(x+y,\frac{x}{x+y})f(x,y)dxdy$

now let $\varphi(x,y)=(x+y,\frac{x}{x+y})=(s,u)$
then $\varphi^{-1}(s,u)=(us,s(1-u))=(x,y)$
and $|det(\varphi^{-1})|=s$ using transformation formula we find 
$\int_{(0,\infty)\times(0,1)}g(s,u)\lambda\mu s e^{-(\lambda u s+\mu s(1-u))}dsdu$ and thus the distribution of (S,U) has density $$\lambda\mu s\mathbb{1}_{\{(s,u)\in(0,\infty)\times(0,1)\}}e^{-(\lambda us+\mu s(1-u))}\qquad (s,u)\in\mathbb{R}^2$$

The only thing I cannot reconstruct are the boundaries. Why is there (before the transformaton) $\int_{(0\times\infty)}\int_{(0\times\infty)}\ldots dxdy$ and after there is $\int_{(0\times\infty)}\int_{(0\times 1)}\ldots dsdu$? I think $\varphi$ tells why? But how?

Comment: Since $U = \frac {X} {X + Y}$, $U \in (0, 1)$ (as $X, Y > 0$)

Comment: Thanks  a lot. Just what I needed.